# Basic Authorization header stripped for oauth/token request

Tags: angular, spring-security-oauth2

I have a serious issue with my Oauth2 authorization and I am slowly giving up after four evenings, so I hope that someone can help me.

**Client:** 
I have an Angular2 client as a separate front-end project. I know how oauth/token post should like, because I already tested it with Postman. The thing is that Authorization header gets stripped and it does not reach server.
Note: I added those Access-Control headers in a desperate attempts to make it work. I am not sure if it makes any difference...

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('angularApp:theBiggestSecret'));

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}oauth/token`, "grant_type=password&scope=read&username=test&password=test&client_id=angularApp&client_secret=theBiggestSecret", headers)
  .subscribe(
  response => console.log(response)
);
```

}

**Server:**
I have Spring MVC application started with "WebApplicationInitializer", with springSecurityFilterChain registered right there in the Initializer.
All configuration is done via annotations, no webapp content at all. Started in an embedded jetty.

I configured both AuthorizationServer and ResourceServer in the same application, I configured CorsFilter in SecurityConfiguration via http.addFilterBefore and I can see it working.

**Problem:**
Well, my authorization header still gets stripped, so basic authentication does not run and I am not getting that access token. However, I believe that CORS is working correctly right now, I am not getting CORS related errors in browser and I can see this as response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2016 21:41:34 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="unauthorized", error_description="There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.3.11.v20160721)
```

This is what gets sent in request:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 115
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
content-type: text/plain
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: cs-CZ,cs;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

Comment: Can you please post code showing how you're using `headers`.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you want. How I use them in http post request in angular? Or some part of server spring configuration? I am not doing anything else than adding cors filter as first filter in springSecurityFilterChain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the `headers` properly in the `post()` method.

You can fix it by doing this:

```
this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}oauth/token`, '<form data>', { headers: headers })
    .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

You can also create your form data in a `URLSearchParams` object and set it as the body so that Angular will automatically set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for you.

```
let body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('grant_type', 'password');
body.set('scope', 'read');
body.set('username', 'test');
body.set('password', 'test');
body.set('client_id', 'angularApp');
body.set('client_secret', 'theBiggestSecret');

this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}oauth/token`, body, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

Comment: Oh man, I see what I did wrong. I put headers and not options there. Thank you. I got a little tired I guess after trying to make cors work. Thank you!

Comment: As a note, if anyone is using Swift and came here with a similar issue, "Authorization" is a reserved header. See Reserved HTTP Headers: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest